# Sencha Touch 2 list in a sheet doesn't show

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I need a list of names to display within a sheet in sencha touch.  The sheet will display all other child items, but not the list. Am I doing something wrong, or does this simply not work?  Here is the code:

```
myList = Ext.create('Ext.dataview.List', {
    store: myStore,
    itemTpl: '{firstName}, {lastName}'
});


mySheet = Ext.create('Ext.Sheet', {
    items: myList
});


Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [ 
        mySheet,
        {
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Click Me',
            handler: function() {
                mySheet.show();
            }
        }
    ]
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

give it height=300. as per your requriment.

Comment: Oh, wow.  I wonder why the height defaults to 0.  Thanks so much!

Comment: The height default to `auto` which means it will automatically resize to the size of your content. However in your case, you are adding a scrollable list, which can't figure out its height because the content overflows. So unfortunately you must set the height manually. Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

@jeremygerrits is almost correct.

IMO `fit` won't work as it will fit *all* the components.

My solution is to use `vbox`/`hbox` on the view container. Then on the components that get added, just add `flex: 1`.

e.g. container:

```
Ext.define('Tm.view.MyContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    xtype: 'holder',

    config: {
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'vbox'
    }
});
```

and component:

```
Ext.define('Tm.view.MyComponent', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'newc',

    config: {
        flex: 1,
        itemTpl: '{option_text}'
    }
});
```

and in controller (assuming container ref been set):

```
    tpl = Ext.create('Tm.view.MyComponent');
tpl.setData(data);
this.getMyContainer().add(tpl);
```

Then any component added displays correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a layout to your panel config:

```
layout: 'fit'
```

This should make the list fill the rest of the space.